# Create angular lib inside folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Hi I am currently using angular 8 with cli version 8.3.17.

I am trying to create an library inside a libs folder instead of the normal projects folder

I tried running:

```
ng g lib libs/test**
```

but I get the error:

> Project name "libs/test" is not valid. New project names must start
>   with a letter, and must contain only alphanumeric characters or
>   dashes. When adding a dash the segment after the dash must also start
>   with a letter. libs/test

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the exact same problem too.

Answer (score 2):

In your `angular.json`, you can change `newProjectRoot` from `projects` to `libs` and create the library by running `ng g lib test` - just note that any apps you generate will also have this path.

Alternatively, `Nrwl NX` includes cli commands which generates libraries in a `/libs` directory by default.