# can't create library in sub scope

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I seem to have a problem with my `@nrwl/cli`/`nx` installation in my angular project. I can not create libraries in "sub scopes" anymore.

```
nx g lib bla/foo-bar

Project name "bla/foo-bar" is not valid. New project names must start with a letter, and must contain only alphanumeric characters or dashes. When adding a dash the segment after the dash must also start with a letter.
```

If i create a library with simple dashes, this works.

```
nx g lib bla-foo-bar
CREATE bla-foo-bar/README.md (1026 bytes)
CREATE bla-foo-bar/karma.conf.js (1024 bytes)
CREATE bla-foo-bar/ng-package.json (154 bytes)
```

Also, if i use the exact schematics it works as well:

```
nx g @nrwl/angular:library bla/foo-bar
CREATE bla/foo-bar/README.md (1026 bytes)
CREATE bla/foo-bar/karma.conf.js (1024 bytes)
CREATE bla/foo-bar/ng-package.json (154 bytes)
```

I did create libraries just as above with the `nx` command in the past. We use this in our project to organize libraries into scopes and sub scopes.

I can not find anything on this subject. My co-worker, using the same code-base and the same comand to create a library does not have this problem. So it must be related to my locally installed `@nrwl/cli` i assume.

I did try to upgrade nrwl/cli (`sudo npm i -g @nrwl/cli`) but that didn't make any difference.

There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739484/create-angular-lib-inside-folder) question on stackoverflow but with less detail and not explaining that the command itself should work.